# i'm getting value in select tag after assigned it should not display in the select tag

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

****Parent table**** : Vehicle

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicle` (
    `vehicle_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `version_number` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vehicle_no` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `vehicle_reg_no` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `vehicle_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `total_seat` INT(15) NOT NULL,
    `route_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `available_seat` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`vehicle_id`)
)
```

---

**Child Table :**   allocate_vehicle

```
CREATE TABLE `allocate_driver` (
    `allocate_driver_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `version_number` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `vehicle_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`allocate_driver_id`),
    INDEX `fk_vehicle_idx` (`vehicle_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `fk_vehicle_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle` (`vehicle_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,

)
```

---

so i given this query : `select veh.* from vehicle as veh JOIN allocate_driver as allDr on veh.vehicle_id!=allDr.vehicle_id`

but  not work properly...  before insert i want the list of vehicle after assign the per vehicle it should not display in list.. any one can tell me.. thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Actually i want allocate the vehicle to the driver.

Comment: I don't see how a select query could allocate a vehicle to a driver. A select query reads in the database. It doesn't write anything.

Comment: i have a vehicle list like Bus-1,Bus-2. if i want to allocate the bus-1 to particular person. before allocate the Bus-1 it should display in the list, after allocated i dont want assinged bus.. thats.. thx for your rly..

Comment: i'm checking only the vehicle_id..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to find the vehicles that is not allocated to `any` driver. Your query will find the vehicles that is not allocated to `some` driver (and will return them once for each of those drivers).

Then this query should give you what you want:

```
SELECT veh.* FROM vehicle AS veh
LEFT JOIN allocate_driver as allDr 
ON veh.vehicle_id = allDr.vehicle_id
WHERE allDr.vehicle_id IS NULL
```